# Toggle image size on click

Tags: jquery, css

How can I toggle an image size when the image is clicked? This is the code I have right now and when the image is clicked it becomes larger but it just stays that way. How can I make it toggle back and forth from the original size to the 600px?

```
$("img").click(function() {
$(this).css({height: "600px", width: "600px"});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("img").click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("bigger");
});
```

in your css add this

```
img .bigger {
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead:

```
$("img").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("test");    
});
```

CSS

```
.test {
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V4u8K/