# how to resize responsive image up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

Anyone know how to resize an image up and down on click.
Example: [nrk.no](https://www.nrk.no/nordland/fortviler-over-gamle-politibiler_-_-kort-fortalt-er-situasjonen-smakritisk-1.13514105)

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggle image size on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850680/toggle-image-size-on-click)

Comment: Whenever you're trying to make something change between two different states (on/off, big/small, visible/hidden, etc.) do a few searches with the word 'toggle'.

Comment: Also take a look at your previous questions, they are all off-topic and if you want to [keep asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) here, then you should visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The website you give as an example uses CSS Transitions to make some of their images grow and shrink. You can learn more about CSS Transitions at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Below is a simple example using JQuery. When you click on the Google logo it will grow and when you click on it again it will shrink.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .box img {
        transition: width .4s,margin .4s,max-width .4s;
        transition-property: width, margin, max-width;
        transition-duration: 0.4s, 0.4s, 0.4s;
        transition-timing-function: ease, ease, ease;
        transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0s;
    }
    .box img.clicked{
        width: 500px;
     }
    </style>

    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('.box img').on('click', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="100" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```